# Nodejs import internal scripts

Tags: node.js, import

I've written a script for logging.  I want to call the logging script in my other local scripts. How can I import logging script into other script? BTW I want to access functions of logging script.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var myscript = eval(fs.readFileSync("logging.js", "utf8"));
myscript.error("hello tester");
```

I use this code in tester.js but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use node's module's properties in logging.js - export your log functions:

```
module.exports.error = error; // or whatever is the function's name in logger.js
```

In your tester.js call logger.js as a module:

```
var logger = require('./logger.js');
logger.error('hello tester');
```

Comment: module.export.error = error;
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'error' of undefined gives error.